# How to avoid blocking using sockets (chat client)

Tags: python, sockets, select, module

I've been looking around all day, but I haven't been able to fix the problem I've got with my chat client here.

Here's the issue: I recently decided to change the client so that it would allow the user to input any message they wanted without having to wait for a reply first (blocking or something stops my program until a reply is in)

I decided to use the select.select module to do so, but after writing a couple different versions of my client today trying to get it to work, I keep getting stuck at this one point.

Whenever I enter a message, the loop gets stuck somewhere, (probably at .recv data)
how can I fix this? Nothing I try gets it to go by that.

Edit: To be more clear, when I run, I get to the point where I input the message, hit enter and then nothing happens at all. It just stays running like that.

```
from socket import *
import select
import sys #because why not?

print("New Chat Client Using Select Module")

HOST = input("Host: ")
PORT = int(input("Port: "))

s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)

print("Trying to connect....")
s.connect((HOST,PORT))
s.setblocking(0)
# Not including setblocking(0) because select handles that. 
print("You just connected to",HOST,)

# Lets now try to handle the client a different way!

while True:
    Incoming_data = [s]
    Exportable_data = []

    Exceptions = []
    User_input = input("Your message: ")

    rlist,wlist,xlist = select.select(Incoming_data,Exportable_data,Exceptions)

    if User_input == True:
        Exportable_data += [User_input]

    for i in rlist:
        data = i.recv(1024)
        if data == "":
            continue

    for i in wlist:
        if Exportable_data is True:
            i.send(Exportable_data)
            continue
```

Is there any way I can override the blocking (that I presume is the problem) when it's set to receive data? Won't s.setblocking(0) make it so it won't block(?) (With or without it still gets stuck)

Thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have separate thread or process which will interact with your socket and another thread, which will accept user input and print chat messages. Interaction between the threads you can do using 2 queues: for incoming and outgoing messages.

Have a look at [threading](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) and [queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) modules.

Comment: I'll see what I can do, but I'm brand new to queues and threading. Do I scrap the select.select module? And then just use threading and queues? Or combine select.select with threading and queues? http://i.imgur.com/xVyoSl.jpg

Comment: I have NO IDEA what to do. It's been all day now and I am maybe 0.000001% closer. How am I supposed to use threading and queues? there is no documentation that helps me set this up with my sockets. And for all I know, I can create a queue. But all I'll do is get stuck witn the same problemn i started with.

Comment: Sorry, I've been patient all day, and now I've just had enough of being lost.